# attach(mesh) issue using @react-three/xr interactive

Tags: reactjs, three.js, virtual-reality, webxr, react-xr

I'm trying to recreate [this three.js attach-to-ray demo](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=drag#webxr_vr_dragging) in @react-three/xr and have come up against a very strange hiccup that I can't figure out.

Using `onSelectEnd` to attach the mesh works just fine, but once it's attached `onSelectEnd` will no longer fire. I've tried using doing it "manually" with `add()`, tried saving the object data in a different spot in userData, but ... nada.

I'm still very new with @react-three/xr so I'm sure it's something obvious, but I'd love a hand if anyone has a moment.  Here's the big giving me trouble, here's a link to the full demo.

```
<Interactive
  ref={groupRef}
  onSelectStart={(e) => {
    console.log("Attach! Works!");
    controlRef.current = e.target.controller;
    const intersections = getIntersections(controlRef.current);

    if (intersections.length > 0) {
      const intersection = intersections[0];
      const object = intersection.object;
      controlRef.current.attach(object); // this causes onSelectEnd to stop firing
      controlRef.current.userData.selected = object;
    }

    onSelectStart?.(e);
  }}
  onSelectEnd={(e) => {
    console.log("Detach! Please!");
    const object = controlRef.current.userData.selected;
    if (object) {
      controlRef.current.detach();
    }
    onSelectEnd?.(e);
  }}
  {...rest}
>
  {children}
</Interactive>;
```